# Turtlebot on willowgarage world in ros hydro

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,i am new in ros.i am just wondering how to run turtlebot gazebo simulator with willowgarage.world in ros hydro.

I have found a link related with my question but it wasn't enough for me.Because it is not a ros hydro solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101936/turtlebot-on-willowgarage-world-in-ros-hydro/) by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2013-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the same launch file as for `turtlebot_empty_world.launch`. You should copy the launch file to a package you've created (any package will do). Then change the line

> ```
> <arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/worlds/empty.world"/>
> ```

to

> ```
> <arg name="world_name" value="worlds/willowgarage.world"/>
> ```

I just tested it and it works fine on my computer. Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) with karma: 438 on 2013-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on 2013-11-17**:
Unfortunately it did not work for me.When i run roslaunch command,only an empty world and a turtlebot on the gazebo screen.Should i change empty_world.launch file?Thanks.

**Comment by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on 2013-11-17**:
So you've copied "turtlebot_empty_world.launch" file into a new package, then renamed the launch file, then launched it? Are you sure you're not launching the old one?

Can you get the mud world to load in gazebo using the launch file here: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_roslaunch_Files_to_Spawn_Models

**Comment by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on 2013-11-17**:
I have just done all you said, respectively.But when i started my new ros package with my renamed launch file,there was only an empty world and a turtlebot on gazebo screen.Also i tried all of roslaunch command with 4 different world which specified on your link,but only willowgarage.world did not work.The other ones have run successfully.

Should i do any other configuration for willowgarage to run on ros hydro?

Thanks.

**Comment by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on 2013-11-17**:
Can you launch empty_world then go to "insert" in Gazebo and try inserting Willow Garage manually?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-11-17**:
Just a hint: willowgarage world is massive, and takes much longer to load in my PC. Maybe you run out of RAM?

**Comment by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on 2013-11-18**:
My programs run with 6 gb ram.Maybe i must try another map.Could you advise another map in gazebo,actually i need a world just like a room.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-11-18**:
You can easily do a simple maze-like map with gazebo's building editor (Ctrl + B).
We did this for showing Turtlebot2 navigation in gazebo: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator/blob/hydro-devel/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world)